# My keyboard is coming up with strange options

Tags: keyboard

A few days ago, before I switched from 13.04 to 13.10, my keyboard started coming up with options `ctrl:swapcaps` and `japan:nicola_f_bs`.

Not realizing at the time that `setxkbmap -option` would temporarily fix the problem, I bought another keyboard which worked the same. File `/etc/defaults/keyboard` shows the right settings but it is dated from the day I installed 13.10. So it is not the source of the problem.

How can I find and fix the source of these odd options?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the dconf-editor and check the settings under org/gnome/desktop/input-sources. There you'll see the xkb-options and you can change them permanently.

Comment: Thank you. After 3 months someone finally tells me what I've been so fruitlessly searching for! Now I have no idea where the problem came from, but in fact doing what you said solves the problem.